# Insert rows based on variables

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I have the below code to insert rows. I find that it is a bit slow. `v` is the number of rows to add and `lRow + 1` is the start position to add from.

```
For q = 1 To v
                    
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows.Add (lRow + 1)
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow).Range.Copy
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow + 1).Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow + 1).Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next q
```

Thanks

Comment: You are adding one row at a time, and using copy/paste hence why the code is running slow. Look into 'Resize'  and consider writing all your data to the table at once (see 'range to table'. Also, Excel autoexpands the table size when writing data directly under an existing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add rows in the loop, seeing how you know the amount of rows to add. Adding all `v` rows outside the loop at once should speed up the code.

```
'Add rows
ExpectedFeesTbl.Rows(lRow + 1).EntireRow.Resize(v).Insert Shift:=xlDown 

'Copy information to new rows
For q = 1 To v
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow).Range.Copy
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow + 1).Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ExpectedFeesTbl.ListRows(lRow + 1).Range.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
                        
    lRow = lRow + 1
Next q

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

note that I added `lRow = lRow + 1` because in your original cost the definition of lRow did not change and therefore each iteration of the loop copied from and pasted to the exact same locations.

**Additionally**, it may be possible to boil down the copy-pasting to a structure that doesn't require a loop. That depends on your workbook structure though

Comment: Thanks, just needed 'Range' between 'ExpectedFeesTbl' and 'Rows'